# Fullcalender change background of cell for previous & past date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I want to dispaly different backaground color of cell in fullcalender. i  tried to get

```
     dayRender: function (date, cell) {
     var today = new Date();
     var start = moment(today).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     var end = new Date();
     var prevous = new Date();
     end.setDate(today.getDate()+1);


      if(date > today && date <= end) {
      cell.css("background-color", "yellow");
      } // this is for previous date 

      if(date > today && date >= prevous) {
      cell.css("background-color", "blue");
      }
    }
```

but dispaly all previous color with blue i want only one how can i do this?

Comment: it seems like date should be < today for previous dates. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have only check your comparison with dates

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {

                var today = new Date();
                 var end = new Date();                
                 end.setDate(today.getDate()-1);                 


                  if( date < end) {
                  cell.css("background-color", "yellow");
                  } // this is for previous date 

                  if(date > today) {
                    cell.css("background-color", "blue");
                  }


            }
```

In your code start and prevous variables are unsued so remove it

Here, all past dates have yellow color and future dates have blue color.

fullcalender.js provides fc-past and fc-future classes in cells, so you can change its color trough css like ::

```
.fc-past{ background-color : yellow } .fc-future{ background-color : blue  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to highlight the background of the cell having an event.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        var date = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + date + '"]').css('background', '#4CB5E5');

}
```